# Spring Boot Docker add external .crt certificate

Tags: java, spring, docker, certificate

I am working on a project that uses docker containers for some Spring Boot projects, and directly Java for a single project.

The project being runned using directly Java and a war file is deployed on a isolated machine, not the one used for the docker containers. The access to this remote server is secured using a .crt file that was created before my arrival.

I am trying to add the .crt file to a Spring Boot project running as a docker container on another machine. What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to rebuild the docker image embedding the certificate too.

As alternative, you can rerun the container mapping the certificate by an external mounted volume.

Comment: Where and how should I embed the certificate? And more important, how can I make sure that the docker deployed spring boot app uses the certificate ? 

When using a local JDK, I can add the certificate to the keystore of the installed JDK. What is the equivalent of that when using a docker container ?

Comment: To answer to your question we must have access to your code and environment, and you know that it is not possibile.

Comment: I was simply asking for a generic way of embedding a .crt file to a Spring Boot project's docker image.